# Picking repeated adjacent numbers in a list

Tags: python

I want to enter a group of numbers, and my output to be a list of the numbers that are repeated more than once, side by side.

**Example input**: 1,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,-1,-1,-1,3,4,3

**Wanted output**: [1,2,1,5,-1]

My code:

```
countnumbers = []
numbers = input().split(',')

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])

sizeoflist = len(numbers)
  
for i in range(sizeoflist - 1):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1]:
        countnumbers.append(numbers[i])
                
mylist = str(countnumbers).replace(' ','')
print(mylist)
```

Example for what my code generates:

**Input**: 1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1

**Output**: [1,1,2,1,1]

So I'm just struggling in how to make it [1,2,1].
I know my code is faulty, I tried using the count function, to `count` but didn't work for me.
And please without the `def` calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a way to remember last known number:

```
countnumbers = []
numbers = input().split(',')

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])

sizeoflist = len(numbers)

current = None
for i in range(sizeoflist - 1):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1]:
        if current is None:
            current = numbers[i]
            countnumbers.append(numbers[i])
    else:
        current = None

mylist = str(countnumbers).replace(' ','')
print(mylist)
```

notice how i used `current` variable

Answer (score 0):

```
countnumbers = []
numbers = input().split(',')

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])

sizeoflist = len(numbers)
  
for i in range(sizeoflist - 1):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1]:
        if len(countnumbers)==0 or not numbers[i] == countnumbers[-1]:
            countnumbers.append(numbers[i])
                
mylist = str(countnumbers).replace(' ','')
print(mylist)
```

Another way of doing it in a little less lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` and filter each group by length. The `gid` stands for for group id.

```
import itertools as it

lst = [1,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,-1,-1,-1,3,4,3]

out = [gid for gid, grp in it.groupby(lst) if len(tuple(grp)) > 1]
```